# Selecting treeviewitem on up/down arrow keys

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a textbox within a stackpanel which is within treeviewitem, can I have Trigger or something by which when I press up/down arrow key and selection goes to next/previous treeviewitem alongwith setting focus to the textbox within that treeviewItem?

Comment: Yes you can have such a trigger. If you would post us your code we would be able to provide you with exact information how the trigger should look alike